Как убрать окно "Подтвердите повторную отправку формы"?


<form method="post">
<textarea id="replace" class="form-control" name="value"></textarea>
 <hr/>
 <input class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" name="SubmitFile" value="Сохранить в лог">
 </form>

    
<?php
if (isset($_POST['SubmitFile']))
{
$content = $_POST['value'];
$file = "file.txt"; // cannot be an online resource
$Saved_File = fopen($file, 'a+');
fwrite($Saved_File, "$content\n");
fclose($Saved_File); 
} 
?>



Нужно, чтобы исполняемый php был на одной странице с формой...
